# VBA Copy Visible Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but I have this code:

```
Sub Purge()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set mrn = ws2.Range("C2:C" & lastRow2)

With wb
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count), Count:=mrn.Rows.Count
End With
For i = 1 To mrn.Rows.Count

ws.Range("A7").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=(mrn.Cells(i, 1).Value), _
         Operator:=xlFilterValues
ws.Range("A3:X" & lastRow).Copy.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
wb.Sheets(i + 2).PasteSpecial

Next i

End Sub
```

The second to last line of code with the Copying Cell type visible is returning me a required object error.  Everything I have in that line seems to be defined so I feel like I have the line written incorrectly.

Briefly, this code creates new tabs depending on the number of rows in table 2 and then filters table 1 and copies the visible cells and pastes them in the first newly created tab.

If anyone has any advice on copying visible cells (I never really was able to understand it) I'd really appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: I think you got it backwards? Try `ws.Range("A3:X" & lastRow).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`?

Comment: Oh my gosh you're right!  Haha thank you so much!